# How to use Font and Text in andEngine?

Tags: android, andengine

That's how I tried to do it:

```
fontTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(1024, 1024, TextureOptions.BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA);
font = FontFactory.createFromAsset(fontTextureAtlas,this,"times.ttf",45f,true,Color.WHITE);
getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(fontTextureAtlas);
```

and then, in code:

```
Text text = new Text(10,10, font,"Some text");
scene.attachChild(text);
```

and all what I see is this:

[image: black blocks instead of text]

Also I tried to use `new Font(fontTextureAtlas,Typeface.DEFAULT,45f,true,Color.WHITE);` to initialize the `font`, but result was almost the same.

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding `font.load();` after  `getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(fontTextureAtlas);`

If that doesn't work try

```
getEngine().getFontManager().loadFont(font);
```

Comment: There's no `load()` method, but I found `reload()` instead. Well, there's no black blocks anymore but I can't see any letters too: http://i.imgur.com/YPvLf.png

Comment: @LemuelHogben Then try `getEngine().getFontManager().loadFont(font);`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me

```
FontFactory.SetAssetBasePath("fontfolder/");

mFont = FontFactory.createFromAsset(mEngine.getFontManager(),
            mEngine.getTextureManager(), 256, 256, TextureOptions.BILINEAR,
            activity.getAssets(), "QUARTZMS.TTF", 32f, true,
            Color.YELLOW_ARGB_PACKED_INT);
    mFont.load();
```

Then I just add `mText = new Text(25, 25, mFont, "Some Text",getVertexBufferObjectManager());`

Answer (score 2):

I have written a blog post on text within andengine which may help http://stuartmct.co.uk/2012/07/16/andengine-creating-and-using-text/